# A radial function that does not depend on a variable must be null

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set. A function $u :\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is radial if $u(x) = u(y),$ when |x|=|y|. Suppose that, for exemple, $u$ doesn't depend on the first variable, that is,
$$
u(r, x_2, ..., x_n) = u(s, x_2, ..., x_n), 
$$
for all real numbers $r,s$ such that $(r, x_2, ..., x_n), (s, x_2, ..., x_n) \in \Omega.$
I would like to know if this implies that $u$ is null.

Any help to disapprove this, or with conditions under which this would work is very welcome.

Edit: If we suppose that $\Omega$ is a ball and $u$ is a $C^1$ function in $\overline{\Omega}$ with the conditions above, but zero in the bondary of $\Omega$, then $u$ would be null?

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags!

Comment: Why null? What about a non-zero constant?

Comment: Think about what happens if $U$ is radially disconnected. And, no, there’s no abstract algebra or functional analysis here; read the descriptions of the tags.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something big, for the ball case, $u$ ignoring its first parameter and being radial is a very strong condition, additional assumptions about continuity are not needed. You only need $u$ to be zero at the north pole or the south pole to make the whole thing constantly zero because of how constrained $u$ is. Also, what does $C^1$ mean? It has been a while since I studied analysis.

Comment: A $C^1$ function is a function with the the first partial derivatives continous. Desr Greg, I understood what you explained, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It does not have to be null.

For example, $u(\vec{x}) = 1$ is consistent with the rules you articulated.

First let's consider the case where $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$. In this case $\Omega$ must be constant.

the set of values of the form $(\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}, 0, 0, c\dots)$ hits every possible modulus in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and, additionally, they all must have the same value.

However, $u$ does not have to be constant in general.

Consider $\Omega = (-1, 1)^n \cup (10+n, 11+n)^n$. (Note that one of the components of $\Omega$ is a box and therefore the maximum modulus in the box is the $\sqrt{n}$ by the definition of distance. I will add $n$ to each of the dimensions of the second component to place it far enough away that its set of moduli is distinct.)

Let $u(\vec{x})$ take the value $1$ when $\vec{x}$ is in $(-1, 1)^n$. Let $u(\vec{x})$ take the value $2$ when $\vec{x}$ is in $(10+n, 11+n)^n$. $u$ is still radial, since no modulus is shared between the two components of $\Omega$.

*I don't know whether we can force $u$ to be constant by insisting on a natural condition for $\Omega$, like convexity or path-connectedness.*

Comment: Thank you Greg. What about if we suppose that $\Omega$ is a ball and $u$ is zero on its boundary?

Comment: @Thiago That case is very similar to the argument for the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$. The set of points of the form $([0, r), 0, 0, \cdots)$ realizes all possible distances within the sphere.

Comment: What about if, additionally, $u$ is a C^1 function in $\overline{\Omega}$?

Comment: I believe $\Omega$ being path-connected is enough to ensure constant. Path-connectedness provides path of balls contained in $\Omega$, and each ball contains diameter parallel to $e^0$ which ensures all the points of the ball to have the same $u$-value.